# Remote validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

below is my code the validation only works without the remote validation. once i include remote validation, it submit the form without completing all the other form validations?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {


      $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                firstName: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
                lastName: "required",
                email: {// compound rule
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        success: "valid",
                        remote: "checkAddress.php"
                },      
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    success: "valid",
                    minlength: 5
                },

                verify: {
                    required: true,
                    success: "valid",
                    minlength: 5,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                },
                address1: "required",
                city: "required",
                province: "required",

                dob: {
                    required: true,
                    date: true,
                    success: "valid"
                },


                captcha_code: {
                    required: true,
                    captcha_code: true,
                    remote: "checkCaptcha.php"      
                }   

            },
            messages: {
               email:{
                   remote: "This email is already registered! One registration per email address."
               },
               captcha_code:{
                  remote: "Enter the right captcha value!."
               }
            },
            onsubmit: true
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was asking was if you have implemented captcha_code as a method? in `captcha_code: true,`.

```
 captcha_code: {
      required: true,
      captcha_code: true,
      remote: "checkCaptcha.php"      
 }
```

Like this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("captcha_code", function(value, element) {
    return (this.optional(element) || /* do something */ );
}, "");
```

I found this captcha demo and it has no captcha_code as method, only required and remote. So I was thinking if you have implemented it.

Here is the script from the demo. http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/captcha/

```
$(function(){
$("#refreshimg").click(function(){
    $.post('newsession.php');
    $("#captchaimage").load('image_req.php');
    return false;
});

$("#captchaform").validate({
    rules: {
        captcha: {
            required: true,
            remote: "process.php"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        captcha: "Correct captcha is required. Click the captcha to generate a new one" 
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("Correct captcha!");
    },
    success: function(label) {
        label.addClass("valid").text("Valid captcha!")
    },
    onkeyup: false
});
```

});

Comment: ah, i never implemented "captcha_code: true" i thought thats how its done in jquery. i am very new to jquery so i just thought thats how its done. maybe thats where the error is?

Comment: try taking that out... "captcha_code: true,", i think it will work perfectly... or let me know what are you trying to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The remote URL is hit passing in the value of the field to which it’s expecting a JSON TRUE/FALSE in return, are you in this one?

Comment: yes i already have a json true/false. strangely my form omits the rest of the validation. i can't seem to find the reason?

Comment: how about putting this 
header('Content-type: application/json');
then echo $output; I think json_encode returns an array in form...

Comment: basically, if a user enter a value for "email" and the captcha, it omits the rest of the form validation, and the form submits. maybe remote validation is not that efficient in jquery. here is the error i am getting: Error: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined on line 471 of jquery.validator

Comment: captcha_code: {
            required: true,
            captcha_code: true,
            remote: "checkCaptcha.php"      
        }
are you defining captcha_code? for "captcha_code: true,"

Comment: yes here is my form captcha: 
<div class="form-row">
      <img id="captcha" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
                               <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="6" maxlength="6" />
                               <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">Reload Image</a>
      </div>   

i am getting captcha code from here: http://www.phpcaptcha.org/

Answer (score 0):

so i changed:

```
email: {// compound rule
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    success: "valid",
                    remote: "checkAddress.php"
            },
captcha_code: {
                required: true,
                captcha_code: true,
                remote: "checkCaptcha.php"      
            }
```

to

```
email: {// compound rule
                    required: true,                  
                    remote: "checkAddress.php"
            },
captcha_code: {
                required: true,
                remote: "checkCaptcha.php"      
            }
```

it works great, wow, you guys rock!!!